# Connect HDMI device to iMac 24"

Tags: mac, imac

Is there any way to use a white iMac 24" as monitor for an external HDMI device?

The iMac has no Video Input port, but is it possible to use some solution with for example USB or Firewire?

Comment: I do not see how you can do this without using a video capture device.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively.

As Hennes has pointed out, you can use a capture device.